# Raster font in Linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, fonts

Is there anyway to get the command prompt font (raster font) into the linux terminal. I would really like to know how to because I just really like this font.

Thanks

Comment: Which "command prompt"? The one in the (non-graphical) console?

Answer (score 1):

"Raster font" sounds like the Windows command-window (and by the way is not a TrueType font).  Linux console fonts can be set, but those are custom-built fonts (not generated or automatically translated from Windows fonts).  Unless someone made one of the Linux console fonts to *imitate* the Windows appearance, you're out of luck.

Further reading:

- [How to Change Your Console Fonts In Ubuntu](https://www.maketecheasier.com/change-console-fonts-in-ubuntu/)
- [Console Fonts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fonts#Console_fonts) (Arch)
- [Linux console fonts screenshots](https://alexandre.deverteuil.net/pages/consolefonts/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant the MS-DOS command prompt; in that case the following might be what you're looking for: [Stack Overflow: which font is used in MS-DOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173428/which-font-is-used-in-ms-dos)